# How to pass the parameter in JSON to append single data in list (Documentum REST API) POSTMAN

Tags: python, api, rest, postman, documentum

I am getting result from GET API as http://localhost:8009/dctm-rest/repositories/myrepo1/groups/group1 as below in JSON :

```
{
    "name": "group",
    "type": "dm_group",
    "definition": "http://localhost:8009/dctm-rest/repositories/myrepo1/types/dm_group",
    "properties": {
        "group_name": "group1",
        "users_names": [
            "Ben Afleck",
            "Jason Rana "
        ],
```

I want to add user Vikas Rana under the users_names column and I am giving below parameter in the POST Method in postman as :

```
{
    "properties":
    {
        "users_names": ["Vikas Rana"]
    }
}
```

But it is replacing the all the names with Vikas Rana. It should be appended as it is a list.

Please help how to pass the parameter in JSON to append the data in list.

Comment: Wouldn't you be using a PUT or PATCH request to do that? I would expect a POST to replace the data - all dependent on the implementation of course.

Comment: Hi @DannyDainton , I tried with PUT and PATCH method as well but getting the error of request method is not supported on this resource.

Comment: It's not going to automatically work without being implemented that way :D I was just saying that a POST would overwrite/replace that value rather than edit it. That's what PUT or PATCH would do. :D

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to define a PUT or PATCH method on your end point. You cannot send a POST/PATCH/PUT request to an endpoint view that only handles GET requests.
Tell me about your app so I can help you better. What package/framework are you using to define your API methods? What is your data base and how are you connecting to it?

Comment: Hi @Hesam Korki , Actually the API is not supporting PATCH and PUT method .This end point is supporting POST method only .These API are documentum REST API and we downloaded these API from opentext .We are using the pycharm to  call these developed API's and database is documentum  and we are connecting from Apache Tomcat application server .

Comment: You can modify APIs to meet your needs. Update your original question with the source code of the API you have downloaded. You should see a view that your URL (/dctm-rest/repositories/myrepo1/groups/group1) points to it. Attach the whole content of that view, then notify me here so I could help you. There are ways to get around update on data with POST method too, but I need to see the source code of the API